# How to convert int to char* in Ardunio

Tags: arduino, char, integer

So I need to convert an int value into a char*  value. Here is my code so far:

```cs
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  char* host = "esp32";
  
  SerialBT.begin("test");
  while (!SerialBT.available()) {
    
  }
  char* ssid = SerialBT.read();
  while (!SerialBT.available()) {
    
  }
  char* password = SerialBT.read();
}
```

I have not really found a solution for this, but here's the error I'm getting:
`invalid conversion from 'int' to 'char*'`

Is there a quick solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Take some time to learn about array, or read [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-input-basics-updated/382007) and the example 2.

Comment: What you're attempting to do is to read a memory address (pointer) for a char from your Bluetooth port, which of course is not meaningful.

Comment: In other words you do NOT want to convert an int to a char *. Check the link that @hcheung provided.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use atoi function:

```cs
int number = atoi( const char * str);
```